# Activate and deactivate GameObject per seconds

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I would like to make an object - Dragon Head, which burst flames for 5 sec and every 3 sec. But I'm not sure how to do this... My script actually looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Dragon_Head_statue: MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject openFire;

private bool IsActive;

void Update()
{
    Invoke("OpenFire", 4);
}

void OpenFire()
{
    IsActive = !IsActive;
    openFire.SetActive(IsActive);
}

}
```

So for now it works like it starts flaming and then it loop activate and deactivate... So it just won't work. I also tried other things like coroutines, InvokeRepeating without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coroutine in conjunction with `new WaitForSeconds(3.0f)` is the perfect solution to this problem. Have a look at this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Dragon_Head_statue: MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject openFire;
    public bool IsActive = false; //IsActive means here that we're in a loop bursting flames, not that we're currently not bursting flames.

    void Start()
    {
        //Start the coroutine
        //5 seconds flame burst, then wait 3 secs
        StartCoroutine(OpenFire(5.0f, 3.0f)); 
    }

    /* function for making this thing stop */
    void StopFlames()
    {
        //Stop the first running coroutine with the function name "OpenFire".
        StopCoroutine("OpenFire");
        IsActive = false; //propage this metadata outside
        //Additionally turn of the flames here if we were just 
        //in the middle of bursting some 
        openFire.SetActive(false);
    }

    IEnumerator OpenFire(float fireTime, float waitTime )
    {
        IsActive = true; //For outside checking if this is spitting fire
        while(true)
        {
            //Activate the flames
            openFire.SetActive(true);
            //Wait *fireTime* seconds
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireTime);
            //Deactivate the flames 
            openFire.SetActive(false);      
            //Now wait the specified time
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            //After this, go back to the beginning of the loop
        }
    }

}
```

You start the coroutine with `StartCoroutine` and then you can stop the coroutine by the function name again. You can also first save the `IEnumerator` returned by `OpenFire` into a local variable and use `StopCoroutine` on that variable if you don't like the string typing.

References:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: So clearly and understandable. I get it now (finally). Thank You for this. It is propably another subject and even not a script, but I'm thinking about how to smooth it yet. I mean, when flames are dezactivated, they just disapperar... What looks weird. There should be an end of them yet like... Uhh I'm not sure how to exmplain it well.. You know, when You create a wave of flames, every particle is fly away. So... It should just stop to push them out, but the created ones should keep fyling. You know what I mean?

Comment: Sounds like the flame spitter should be implemented by letting him create a `GameObject` for every fireball,giving them a start velocity and destroy them after some time. That way, when the game object / script is deactivated, it just stops creating more fire balls. Is it currently a particle system or emitter? Then it should be possible to change the `.emit` field of that emiter sothat it just stops emitting more particles, see http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleEmitter-emit.html or http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Stop.html. Otherwise open a new question.

Comment: I was thinking the same... To make it as fire ball launcher instead of flame weaver. Yes I currently use just particle system. I didn't heard about emitter before... I'll check out these links.